# Send base URL for my custom block

Tags: theming, 8

In my Drupal 8 site, I am developing a custom block in my module custom, with some text and some images. I created a template, and everything works fine. Now I need to add some images for my custom block, and I don't know how to pass the base URL to call those images.

In Drupal 7 I used the following code.

```
function bloques_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();

    $ruta = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/' . drupal_get_path("module", "mymodule");
    $link = $GLOBALS['base_url'] ;   

  switch ($delta) {

//footer
    case 'footer':
      $block['subject'] = '';
      $block['content'] = leer_template('footer.tpl', array('%ruta%' => $ruta, '%link%' => $link));
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Everything works well, but in Drupal 8 it is a little different. The problem comes with `build()`.

```
    public function build() {
    $ruta = 'holamundo',        
    return array(
        '#theme' => 'mymodule',
        '#title' => 'my title ',
        '#ruta' => '<p>' . $ruta . '</p>'
    );
```

}

Just the title works in the template file; `$ruta` is not working.

```
  <h2>My Custom Block {{ title }}-{{ ruta }}</h2>
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to declare the base URL (just like I did in Drupal 7).

```
  $ruta = $GLOBALS['base_url'] . '/' . drupal_get_path("module", "bloques");
```

Comment: Yes declaring base_url is correct and the same above code is working fine.
Can you once try by removing <p> tag and also check declared "variables" in hook_theme for ruta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try template_preprocess_block(&$variables). There is a global $base_url variable. Create variable for block template:

```
function your_module_preprocess_block(&$variables){
  global $base_url;
  $variables['base_url'] = $base_url;

}
```

Now you can use {{base_url}} in twig template of your block.

Comment: it doesnt work for me. i put the function in the block.php for my module.module and try to call the {{base_url}}  in my twig file. But it doesnt work.

Comment: You have to put this function in your module_name.module file and not in block.php. After that this variable {{base_url}} should be accessible in all block templates.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/8.2.x

Comment: And the cache have to be cleared after adding this function.

Comment: Thank you, if it works for you please mark it as right answer.

Comment: sorry, i am new at this, how do i do that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work


You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).